# Serialize Dictionary<int,object> using JSON.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

I'm trying to use JSON.net to serialize a Dictionary.

Using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theDict);
```

Here is my result

```
{
  "1": {
    "Blah1": false,
    "Blah2": false,
    "Blah3": "None",
    "Blah4": false
  },
  "2": {
    "Blah1": false,
    "Blah2": false,
    "Blah3": "None",
    "Blah4": false
  },
  "3": {
    "Blah1": false,
    "Blah2": false,
    "Blah3": "None",
    "Blah4": false
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to serialize this dictionary such that the keys are rendered as valid javascript variables?

I am also open to other strategies of serializing the dictionary.

Comment: They are valid. What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: Technically, your variable["1"] *is* valid.

Comment: What is going to be the consumer of the produced JSON? If it is going to be javascript then just use `JSON.parse` deserialize the JSON back to a JS object.

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Are those indexs rather than variables?

So object[1] vs object.1?

Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: `object["1"]` not  `object[1]`.

Comment: @L.B It actually is in JS (and JSON)... JSON actually makes this *formal* by requiring that all *keys* are quoted strings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is the correct way to generate the JSON for `Dictionary<int,...>`. The reason is that [JSON *requires* that all keys are quoted-string literals](http://json.org/).

JS is a little more relaxed in this regard: but JSON is a restricted form of JS object literals. In any case, *all property names in JavaScript are strings*. (They are implicitly converted as needed.) Thus, `({1: 2})["1"])` and `({"1": 2})[1])` are as equally valid in JS (and both evaluate to `2`), but only `{"1": 2}` is valid JSON.

If the target Type to deserialize back into is `Dictionary<int,...>` then it will automatically take care of the conversions in the keys to `int`, IIRC.

I am not aware of a way to get JSON.NET to generate non-JSON directly ;-) It could be done with looping the top-level construct, e.g. each `KeyValuePair<int,...>` and generating the JSON for each individual entry along with the "modified" JS code:

```
foreach (var p in dict) {
    var k = p.Key;
    var v = p.Value;
    Emit(string.Format(
        "var name{0} = {1};",
        k, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v)));
}
```

Where `Emit` is whatever is used to collect the output... I would recommend "just normal JSON" if at all possible, though.

Happy coding.

Comment: I was able to puzzle out as much from the comments above and a little research, but it's always nice to get a very specific explanation.  Thanks!